# How to fix a bug in an external Strapi plugin?

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I installed this strapi plugin: https://github.com/kwinyyyc/strapi-plugin-wysiwsg-react-md-editor

It had a bug - styles did not apply to relevant elements. I fixed this bug by downloading the package, placing it in `/plugins` folder and adding the styles myself.

Although it works, I doubt that this is a good solution for performance and project structure reasons.

So, the questions are:

- Could I fix this bug by creating and `/extension` folder and trying to extend this plugin with `strapi-admin.js`?
- Would I need to create middlewares and somehow inject the styles in the component?
- How do you fix Strapi plugins without messing around in source code?

Thanks!

Comment: Salut Dan, can you tell us the strapi version? is it 3x or 4x? in your question with "strapi-admin.js" i guess is v4 but please specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the only way to fix external strapi plugins is to go into the `node_modules` folder and fixing it there.

There's a good package for that: [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).